# Problem on inequality with power sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Let $m$ and $n$ are positive integer

> Can it be shown that, For every $m\ge 5$
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^ni^m-m^i>0\iff n=2,3,...,m$$

Example: let $m=5$, choose any $n$ between $2$ to $5$, now let $n=2$ then $\sum_{i=1}^2i^5-5^i=(1^5-5^1)+(2^5-5^2)=-4+7=3>0$

More on observation, $\sum_{i=1}^ni^m-m^i=0$ holds only for $(m,n)=\{(1,1),(2,3),(2,4)\}$

Score Pari/GP

```
for(m=5,50,for(n=1,50,if(sum(i=1,n,i^m-m^i)>0,print([m,n]))))
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking about proving for every $m \ge 5$ that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i^m - m^i) \gt 0 \iff n = 2, 3, \, \ldots \, , m \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

First, consider the $\impliedby$ direction, starting at $n = 2$. Define

$$f_1(m) = 1 - m + 2^m - m^2 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

As you've already shown, $f_1(5) = 3 \gt 0$. Differentiating $f_1(m)$ gives

$$f'_1(m) = -1 + \ln(2)2^{m} - 2m \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

You can easily verify $f'(5) \gt 0$ and $f'(m)$ is an increasing function of $m$ (e.g., by induction using $2m \gt m + 1$). Thus, $f(m) \gt 0$ for $m \ge 5$. Next, since the natural logarithm is a strictly increasing function, consider the values of $i$ where

$$i^m \gt m^i \iff m\ln(i) \gt i\ln(m) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Define

$$f_2(i) = m\ln(i) - i\ln(m) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

It's fairly easy to confirm $f_2(3) \gt 0$ for all $m \ge 5$. Differentiating here gives

$$f'_2(i) = \frac{m}{i} - \ln(m) \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

With $m = 5$, this gives $f'_2(3) \approx 0.057$. Also, $g(m) = \frac{m}{3} - \ln(m) \implies g'(m) = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{m} \gt 0$, so $f'_2(3) \gt 0$ for all $m \ge 5$. Note $f'_2(i)$ is a monotonically decreasing function, with $\lim_{i \to \infty}f'_2(i) = -\ln{m} \lt 0$. Thus, there's only *one* value of $i$ where $f'_2(i) = 0$.

We therefore have $f_2(3) \gt 0$, with $f_2(i)$ reaching a maximum at $i = \frac{m}{\ln(m)} \lt m$ and then decreasing. Since $f_2(m) = 0$, this means $f_2(i) \gt 0$ for all $3 \le i \le m - 1$. This shows \eqref{eq4A} is true, so the value being summed in \eqref{eq1A} is positive, for all these $i$. As such, the left side summation in \eqref{eq1A} is positive for all $3 \le n \le m$.

Combining this with $f_1(m) \gt 0$ in \eqref{eq2A} means the $\impliedby$ direction of \eqref{eq1A} is true for all $2 \le n \le m$.

---

With the $\implies$ direction, $n = 1$ gives a summation of $1 - m \lt 0$. As discussed above, with \eqref{eq5A} giving $f_2(i) \lt 0$ for $i \gt m$, this means each extra term being summed is negative for $n \ge m + 1$. Thus, if the summation is negative for $n = m + 1$, it'll be negative for all $n \ge m + 1$. To check on this, using the $m^i$ summation being of a geometric series gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}(i^m - m^i) & = \sum_{i=1}^{m+1}i^m - \sum_{i=1}^{m+1}m^i \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{m+1}i^m - \frac{m(m^{m+1} - 1)}{m - 1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Since $i^{m} \lt x^{m}$ for $i \lt x \le i + 1$ means $\int_{i}^{i+1}i^{m}dx \lt  \int_{i}^{i+1}x^m dx \implies i^{m} \lt \int_{i}^{i+1}x^m dx$, then using this and combining the integrals for all $1 \le i \le m - 1$ in the summation gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{i=1}^{m+1}i^m  - \frac{m(m^{m+1} - 1)}{m - 1} \\
& \lt \int_{1}^{m}x^m dx + m^m + (m + 1)^m - \frac{m(m^{m+1} - 1)}{m - 1} \\
& = \left. \frac{x^{m+1}}{m + 1} \right|_{1}^{m} + m^m + (m + 1)^m - \frac{m(m^{m+1} - 1)}{m - 1}\\
& = \frac{m^{m+1} - 1}{m + 1} + m^m + (m + 1)^m - \frac{m(m^{m+1} - 1)}{m - 1} \\
& = \frac{m(m^{m}) + (m + 1)(m^m) + (m + 1)^{m+1} - 1}{m + 1} - \frac{m(m^{m+1} - 1)}{m - 1} \\
& = \frac{(m - 1)((2m + 1)(m^m) + (m + 1)^{m+1} - 1) - (m + 1)m(m^{m+1} - 1)}{(m + 1)(m - 1)} \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Define

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f_3(m) & = (m - 1)((2m + 1)(m^m) + (m + 1)^{m+1} - 1) - (m + 1)m(m^{m+1} - 1) \\
& = (2m^2 - m - 1)(m^m) + (m - 1)(m + 1)^{m+1} - (m - 1) \\
& \; \; \; \; - (m^3 + m^2)(m^{m}) + (m^2 + m) \\
& = (-m^3 + m^2 - m - 1)(m^m) + (m - 1)(m + 1)^{m+1} + m^2 + 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

This gives $f_3(5) = -144600$. Next, simplify \eqref{eq9A} by using $0 \gt (-m - 1)(m^m) + m^2 + 1$ to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f_3(m) & \lt (-m^3 + m^2)(m^m) + (m - 1)(m + 1)^{m+1} \\
& = (-m + 1)(m^{m+2}) + (m - 1)(m + 1)^{m+1} \\
& = (m - 1)((m + 1)^{m+1} - m^{m+2})
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

As done before using the natural logarithm,

$$(m + 1)^{m+1} \lt m^{m+2} \iff (m + 1)\ln(m + 1) \lt (m + 2)\ln(m) \tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$

Next, define

$$f_4(m) = (m + 1)\ln(m + 1) - (m + 2)\ln(m) \tag{12}\label{eq12A}$$

Note $f_4(5) \approx -0.5155$. Taking the derivative, plus using the logarithm [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Properties) that $\ln(x) \le x - 1$ for $x \gt 0$, gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f'_4(m) & = \ln(m + 1) + \frac{m + 1}{m + 1} - \ln(m) - \frac{m + 2}{m} \\
& = 1 - \left(1 + \frac{2}{m}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{m + 1}{m}\right) \\
& = - \frac{2}{m} + \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{m}\right) \\
& \le - \frac{2}{m} + \frac{1}{m} \\
& = -\frac{1}{m} \\
& \lt 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{13}\label{eq13A}$$

This shows $f_4(m) \lt 0$ for all $m \ge 5$, so $f_3(m) \lt 0$ in \eqref{eq10A}. This confirms $\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}i^m  - \frac{m(m^{m+1} - 1)}{m - 1} \lt 0$ in \eqref{eq7A}, which proves the $\implies$ direction in \eqref{eq1A} always holds.

Comment: Seeing $f_3(m)$ one would think "this guy is crazy", I'm actually impressed you managed to get something useful from it.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma 1:** $2^m> m^2+m-1, \forall m>5$.

When $m=5, 2^5=32>29=5^2+5-1$. If $2^m>m^2+m-1$ then $$2^{m+1}-[(m+1)^2+(m+1)-1]\\>2(m^2+m-1)-(m+1)^2-(m+1)+1 = m(m-1)-3 >0.$$

**Lemma 2:** $i^j < j^i, \forall i>j>e.$

We check the first derivative of the function $f(x)=x^\frac 1x$:
$$f'(x)=x^{\frac 1x -2}(1-\ln x) < 0, \forall x>e.$$

**First we prove $\Leftarrow$.**

From the lemmas
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (i^m-m^i)=1+2^m-m-m^2+\sum_{i=3}^n(i^m-m^i)>0.$$

**Next we prove $\implies$.**

If $n=1$, it's trivial.

If $n>m$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (i^m-m^i)=\sum_{i=1}^{m+1} (i^m-m^i) + \sum_{i>m+1} (i^m-m^i) \le \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} (i^m-m^i) \text{ via Lemma 2}$$

Note that $e^{-\frac km} \ge 1-\frac km \implies \left(1-\frac km \right)^m \le e^{-k}, k=0, 1, \cdots, m-1$

Hence
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{m+1} (i^m-m^i) = \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} i^m - \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} m^i = m^m\left(\left(1+\frac 1m\right)^m + \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \left(1-\frac km\right)^m \right) - \frac{m^{m+2} - m}{m-1}\\
< m^m \left(e+\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k} - \frac{m^2-m^{1-m}}{m-1}\right) < m^m \left(e+\frac{1}{1-e^{-1}} - m\right) \approx m^m(4.3003-m) <0.\blacksquare
$$